# Measure and probability : what would be $\mu(A\mid B)$?

Tags: probability, measure-theory

I know that a probability space $(\Omega ,\mathcal F,\mathbb P)$ is in fact a measure space with a $\sigma -$algebra $\mathcal F$ and a measure $\mathbb P$. I know that if $A,B\in \mathcal F$ with $\mathbb P(B)>0$, then, by the conditional probability,
$$\mathbb P(A\mid B)=\frac{\mathbb P(A\cap B)}{\mathbb P(B)}.$$

But in a measure space unspecified $(X,\mathcal M,\mu)$, what does $\mu(A\mid B)$ mean when $A,B\in \mathcal M$ ?

Comment: It should be $\mathbb{P}(B)$ in the denominator, and not $\mathbb{P}(A)$.

Comment: @Karthik: Yes of course. I corrected it. Thanks

Comment: "in a measure space unspecified" You mean, when the measure μ is not a probability measure?

Comment: @Did: Yes, exactly.

Comment: why the downvote ?

Comment: Then $\mu(A\mid B)$ could be defined as $\mu(A\cap B)/\mu(B)$, as in the probability case, provided $\mu(B)$ is not zero and not infinite. But before that, and more importantly, **which context did you meet this in?** (Re downvotes, you could concentrate less on them and more on raising the quality of your questions. The present one, for example, is quite unclear, as witnessed by the (probably offtopic) answer posted below and by the comments above.)

Answer (score 0):

I think the interpretation is as follows.

Suppose we consider the collection

\begin{eqnarray}
\mathcal{M}_{B}=\{C: C=D\cap B,~D\in \mathcal{M}\}.
\end{eqnarray}

This denotes the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the subsets of $B$. In this context, $\mu(A|B)$ is the measure of the set we obtain by substituting $D=A$ above, measured relative to the measure $\mu(B)$ of the set $B$.